# Does Fallout 4 have a gore filter?

Tags: fallout-4

I am considering buying an Xbox One to play Fallout 4, as my PC currently could not play it as well as a console, so I am going to buy one while I wait for my gaming PC.

However, this would mean I would actually have to ask my parents if I can play it, unlike PC games which I can obtain on my own. My parents only concerns are gore and language, but for Fallout 4, it is really only gore since there is so little profanity.

Is there an option where I can turn gore off playing Fallout 4 on Xbox One?

Comment: Currently I don't believe there is any gore/profanity filter. Perhaps there will be someone who makes a mod in the future. OOC are you under the age of 13?

Comment: If you're looking for lack of blood/gore, Fallout is the wrong game to convince your parents for. We're talking about a game with a perk called "Bloody Mess" (at least FO3 had that). And FO4 is no less violent.

Comment: As commented below, Xbone and PS4 will both be featuring Fallout 4 modification.

Comment: On the PC version you can disable gibs (a gore thing) entirely, console not so much.

Comment: I'm am 16 lol, crazy parents when it comes to video games. Completely forgot about being able to use mods on Xbox one, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there is no built-in gore or profanity filter as of now.

On [PC](http://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136904735274/), you can try `bDisableAllGore=1` in the `.ini` file to remove gore from the kill animations, but it won't remove the bloody body part decorations used in super mutant hideouts.